# How to handle inserting data into bit columns using csvhelper?

Tags: c#, bulkinsert, csvhelper

I have a csv file with one of the column types a bit. I have a map in my c# code to specify the datatype to the Datatable column type.

```
public static Type GetType(SqlDbType sqlType, bool isNullable)
{
  switch(sqlType)
  {
    case SqlDbType.Bit:
      return isNullable ? typeof(bool?) : typeof(bool);
    ....
  }
}

datatable.Columns.Add(column.Name, GetClrType(columnType, false));
```

I am getting `String '0' was not recognized as a valid Boolean.` when bulk inserting the data on the bit column. Any idea how can I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Changing it to the below worked

```
case SqlDbType.Bit:
  return isNullable ? typeof(int?) : typeof(int);
```